# How to create Multiple Pages using Different Page Layout but using Same URL

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, url, community-builder, experience-cloud

I have a requirement to create 3 different Home Pages for a Community Site using Experience Builder based on Community User level (Guest(Not logged in User), Basic, Privileged)

Based on the User Level, I have to display respective Home Page which might be using different Layout. Is it possible with Experience Builder so that I don't need to create different Pages with different URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a feature called page variation to generate different versions of the same page.

This does not change url and you can render different layouts for different audience by assigning respective page.

Check the [docs](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/create-a-partner-community/apply-a-page-variation) here on how to create page variations.